# Polynomial Time Special Case of Subset Sum Problem

Tags: algorithms, subset-sum

From Chapter 35 of Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.

> EXACT-SUBSET-SUM is an exponential-time algorithm in general, although it is a polynomial-time algorithm in the special cases in which $t$ is polynomial in $|S|$ or all the numbers in $S$ are bounded by a polynomial in $|S|$.

I fail to see the reason here. Can someone explain or drop a hint?

Comment: There's a dynamic programming algorithm for these cases. Note that if the numbers can be negative then even $ t=0 $ isn't enough for polynomial time and the first case is wrong.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What do you believe is the running time of EXACT-SUBSET-SUM, in each of those two cases?

Comment: @D.W. I think if we set t to a sufficiently high power of |S| that we either don’t achieve the sum or achieve it at the last iteration, then we will never encounter any element greater than t in list L, eventually including sums of all possible subsets in the list, i.e. the exponential case.

Comment: @CommandMaster But the statement quoted here explicitly refers to the EXACT-SUBSET-SUM algorithm.